# How to generate graph for rate of traversal

Tags: matlab, implementation, simulation

In Fig 20 of this [Coverage paper](http://www.ynl.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/publications/pdf1999/iros99/akino/akino.pdf), shows the rate of coverage of robot navigation. For 5000 iterations, how does one plot the coverage rate versus the number of planned points visited by robot in a simulation? I do not know how to implement the following formula and how to populate the data for matrix A.

`Coverage C = 1/N * (summation i=1 to N, A(i) )`

`A` represents the coverage for each cell.

- `A(i) = 1` when the cell i is covered
- `A(i) = 0`, otherwise

The robot's workspace `N` is a square terrain of 20*20 normalized cell units.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The formula just computes the coverage as the mean value of matrix A, so in Matlab just:

```
C = mean(A);
```

assuming indeed A(i) == 1 if cell i is covered, and 0 otherwise.
To compute the coverage for a certain robot track, initizialize A to 20x20 = 400 zero values, discretize each robot position to the cell grid, and set each of those cells to A(i) = 1. The exact implementation of how to do this really depends on your code, and I can not help you with that.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Given:

- `N` -- 20x20 matrix indicating the robot's workspace.
- Some kind of function that determines whether or not a cell in the robot's workspace is "covered". Let's call it `coverfun` such that `A=coverfun(N,num_planned_pts_visited)`. Likely, you will have to figure out how to write this function from domain-specific knowledge, the paper, or from emailing the authors of the paper.

Compute:

- The coverage quantity `C`.

The code will probably look something like this:

```
MAX_PTS_VISITED = 5000;

C = zeros(MAX_PTS_VISITED,1);
for i = 1:MAX_PTS_VISITED,
   A = coverfun(N, i);
   C(i) = mean(A);
end

plot(1:MAX_PTS_VISITED, C);
```